# Implement mailchimp oauth2 authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, mailchimp

I want to implement mailchimp oauth2 authentication.
I am reading here https://mailchimp.com/developer/release-notes/stricter-rules-for-url-matching-oauth-2/
that  **only support exact matching on the redirect URI**
My question is simple, how would I know which user is the one that actually authorizes my application. When I am trying to add the current user id I am getting an error

```
    call_back_url = url_for(controller: '/webhooks/mailchimp', action: 'handler', only_path: false, id: current_user.id)
Error call back uri mismatch.
```

Is there another way to add info about the user on the webhook callback?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out how, I can add a state param on the redirect_to url, and then this is available on the webhook callback.

```
    query_params = "response_type=code&client_id=#{client_id}&redirect_uri=#{call_back_url}&state=#{current_user.id}"
```